# All Downloads Fail at 95-to-99%

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Downloads stopping (not failing) at 99% was a common topic at
computer help forums years ago.  There were long lists of possible
causes, which wasn't very helpful for most people.

I can download static images like jpg, png, bmp.  Anything else
abruptly fails at 95-to-99%.  The file host does not matter.  The
built-in Tor download applet and download managers have the
same problem.  It's like someone turning off a switch right before
the download completes.

To quote an old expression, I hope the cure is not worse than
the disease.

Comment: Do you have a question?

AFAIK this is usually a webserver issue. Can you give a definite example of where this is happening? What version of Tor Browser are you using? What OS? I just tested downloading from https://www.torproject.org/download/ using the latest Tor Browser and I am not seeing this issue. If you try to do the same, do you get the same issue?

Comment: Did you try a different circuit? Are you using some anti-virus or firewall?